# Как упростить регулярное выражение ?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

```
"[g-zG-Z||а-яА-Я||( )||~||`||!||@||#||$||%||^||&||*||(||)||_||+||/||ё||Ё||!||\"||№||;||:||?||-||=||\\[||\\]]";
```

Оно работает :) Но хотелось бы как то короче записать. Суть выражения такова, что оно в паре с DocumentFilter не дает пользователю вводить никаких посторонних символов, кроме тех, что касаются HEX системы исчисления.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для 16-ричных символов проще указать разрешённые символы, чем искать нарушителей:

```
[0-9A-Fa-f]+
```

Comment: А как сделать логическое НЕ ? То есть если символ не будет подходить под [0-9A-Fa-f]

Comment: Все, разобрался. Спасибо!